# Vertically aligning content inside flexbox

Tags: css, position, flexbox

In our web application I'm trying to vertically aligning the content inside flexboxes. What I want is to anchor content to the bottom (left) corner of a parent div, so that the content grows upwards instead of down.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg61V.png).

More specifically, what I'm trying to achieve is this: I have a column of *n* elements, evenly spaced out using flexbox. These elements all have a toolbar that is activated on hover. This toolbar is supposed to be anchored to the bottom of the element. Problem is, the height of the element is not given, and overflows its container as expected. But it severely complicates the placement of the toolbar. I do not want to stretch the elements, their maximum height should be the height of its content (something that rules out all the `position: absolute` hacks and solutions I've tried up until now).

I envision that the simplest solution would be to anchor the element to the bottom left corner of the flexing element, and have it grow upwards. This way it is trivial to anchor the toolbar to the bottom, and better supports variable heights and number of elements. I can not figure out how to do it, or even if it is possible at all.

[Code example](http://jsbin.com/tavubatu/1/)

Here I want the content text to be at the bottom left of the element, and the element box to grow (and overflow) upwards instead of down. Remove the `overflow: hidden` to see what I mean by growing/overflowing downwards.

Comment: Sure, I'll have my issue recreated very soon.

Comment: I've added a code example to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need  `justify-content:flex-end` and imbricate 2 `flex` levels to trigger `justify-content` within childs.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/kybDL/)** *with 2 `p` in `body` as container*.

---

Base CSS

```
body {/* used as a box for demo, size it */
  width:600px;
  height:250px;
  margin:auto;
  display:flex;
}
p {
  border:solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;/* vertical! */
  padding:5px;
}
p+p {
  justify-content: flex-end;/* drop down content */
}
```

---

to see content overflowing at the top you must go against the natural flow, so,

you need to set content in `absolute` `position` within a `relative` parent :

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jEfIF/)**

---

HTML same as above + text wrapped in `span` for second paragraph.

```
body {
  width:600px;
  height:150px;
  margin:auto;
  display:flex;
}
p {
  border:solid;
  padding:5px;
  margin:1em;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
}
p + p span  {
 display:block;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%
}
```

Comment: Close :) But I want to have the content be a bit more firmly anchored to the bottom than this approach allows for. If I adjust the size of the body to 150px, (as I've done here)[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gBIor), I want the overflowing text to flow over the top of the container, not the bottom as it does here.

Comment: @TrondBremnes in this case it is much more simple and classic : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jEfIF/ one level in flex  then positionning with relative/absolute;

Comment: Plus one for "imbrigate"; had to look that one up.